# Activity having noHistory open Intent chooser finish the calling Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish, android-intent-chooser, nohistory

I have a LiveChat activity having noHistory in AndroidManifest.xml. LiveChat activity open file chooser to choose image or video.

The problem is that when file chooser open it finish the activity because of noHistory set in activity.

I have to keep noHistory flag with activity because LiveChat activity is PiP activity and when it finish it open two instances of App. I want activity should not finish when file chooser is open.

I try below snip of code when opening file chooser

```
getIntent().removeFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

but its not working. Is it possible to do so. Thanks

Comment: You cannot use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` if you want to open a file chooser. You'll need to find another way to solve your. "2 instances of App" problem. Please explain more about that problem as it isn't clear why you need `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`.

Comment: I need FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY because of my activity which is open file chooser is PiP activity. I make call functionality in it when I press back, activity launch in PiP so that call should not disconnect and when I close PiP two instances are get open.

Comment: I'm sorry, your explanation is not clear. Why are 2 instances open? Please edit your question and paste the relevant parts of your manifest. There should not be 2 instances open unless you are doing something strange.

Comment: @DavidWasser I got the solution please check my answer.

Comment: I saw your answer, but you still must be doing something wrong if you end up with 2 instances of your `Activity`. Whatever, if you're happy with the solution, that's the important thing.

Comment: @DavidWasser I applied the solution and check it my all test cases two instances are not creating. Any way thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone faces the same problem he/she can close multiple instances of PiP without using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY using below snip of code.

```
@Override
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);

    if (getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
        finishAndRemoveTask();
        //when user click on Close button of PIP this will trigger, do what you want here
    }
    else if (getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
        //when PIP maximize this will trigger
    }
}
```